# how to get server pc's date from client's pc by php?

Tags: php

I am accessing `192.168.1.232` pc by `192.168.1.232/project` from local pc. while doing `date()` in `192.168.1.232/project` on local pc I get date of local pc. But I want to get `date` of 192.168.1.232...how can I get?

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
 echo $date_current = date('d/m/o'); //here I want server's date instead of local machine
```

Comment: add your code will helps

Comment: ok I have added code!!

Comment: maybe the server date is the same as the date on local machine? or `Asia/Calcutta` timezone is the timezone your local machine is in?

Comment: no..if you change local pc date...it will change